# Kivy popup change image size

Tags: python, image, kivy

I have a popup in Kivy, and I would like for it to have an image that has a `size_hint` of `(0.5, 0.5)`, but when I try to set this, the image moves.

My current code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Open Popup', on_press=self.open)

    def open(self, button):
        Popup(title='Popup', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), content=Image(source='testing.png', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))).open()


TestApp().run()
```

The current code gives this outcome:
[image: Example]

If anyone could help me, that would be great!

Comment: When you say the image moves, where do you want it to be? (bottom left, centered, etc)

Comment: I would like the image to be centered

Comment: Check the answer I gave and let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the pos_hint parameter. This should fix it:

```
    def open(self, button):
        Popup(title='Popup',
              size_hint=(0.5, 0.5),
              content=Image(source='testing.png',
                            size_hint=(0.5, 0.5),
                            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})).open()
```

More info at https://blog.kivy.org/2014/01/positionsize-of-widgets-in-kivy/

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [Pixlr Editor](https://pixlr.com/editor/) to resize the image, and then use a turtle to move the image where you want:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.turtle
t.shape("testing.png")
#use the .forward() functions to move it
t.forward(10)
```